# Abrir aplicação em segundo plano em C - Linux

Tags: c, linux

Estou programando um watchdog para meu sistema, no começo do código eu necessito executar a aplicação em segundo plano, para isso utilizo o comando:

system("./meuprograma&");

Porém o programa entende o '&' (necessário para abrir processo em segundo plano) como um parâmetro esperado pela aplicação.

O comando "./meuprograma&" executado diretamente pelo terminal funciona corretamente, porém em C está ocorrendo este problema.

O importante é conseguir abrir minha aplicação em segundo plano e continuar com a execução do watchdog. Alguma ideia? Obrigado!

Comment: Creio que a solução será um pouco mais complexa. Você deve usar fork() com as rotinas exec(). Dá uma procurada sobre isso. Se eu tiver tempo, posto uma resposta. Mas para isso precisarei testar e aí está a falta de tempo. :-) veja isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319484/regarding-background-processes-using-fork-and-child-processes-in-my-dummy-shel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu implemente o código a seguir (baseado em outros códigos, não tenho mais a fonte deles) que faz mais ou menos o que você deseja.

O código consiste em realizar o `fork` do processo e então alterar a sessão de execução do mesmo, de modo que o processo pai pode ser encerrado sem que o processo filho seja encerrado. Assim, o processo filho se torna órfão. É equivalente ao funcionamento de um daemon:

```
    pid_t pid = 0;
    pid_t sid = 0;

    pid = fork();
    if ( pid < 0 ) {
            puts("Falha ao criar o processo filho.");
            return -1;
    }

    if ( pid > 0 ) {
            puts("Eu sou o proceso pai! Hora de finalizar!");
            return 0;
    }

    umask(0);
    sid = setsid(); // altera a sessão.
    if ( sid < 0 ) {
            return -2; // falha ao alterar a sessão.
    }

    int dummy = chdir("/"); // retorno não utilizado... deveria checar por erros ;D

    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);
```

O comando `chdir("/");` alterar o diretório de trabalho do processo. Você pode utilizar outro diretório. No meu caso, deixei o `"/"` pois o processo executa em um ambiente de `chroot`.

Comment: Se o watchdog precisar monitorar output do subprocesso, pode ser interessante usar popen().